# Integrate $\int \frac{dx}{(x-1)\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}$ using any method

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I have an expression

$$\int \frac{1}{(x-1)\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}dx$$

to integrate, which I don't know how to integrate. I tried to factorize and solve, but got really ugly expression at the end.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: These kind of integrals can be evaluated by using Euler's substitution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That edit makes it easier. Let $x-\frac12=\frac{\sqrt3}2\tan\theta$. Then
$$\begin{align}\int\frac{dx}{(x-1)\sqrt{x^2-x+1}} & =\int\frac{d\theta}{\frac{\sqrt3}2\sin\theta-\frac12\cos\theta}=\int\frac{d\theta}{\sin(\theta-\pi/6)} \\
& =-\ln(\csc(\theta-\pi/6)+\cot(\theta-\pi/6))+C_1 \\
& =\ln\left(\frac{\sin(\theta-\pi/6)}{1+\cos(\theta-\pi/6)}\right)+C_1 \\
& = \ln\left(\frac{\frac{\sqrt3}2\sin\theta-\frac12\cos\theta}{1+\frac{\sqrt3}2\cos\theta+\frac12\sin\theta}\right)+C_1\end{align}$$
From the Pythagorean theorem,
$$\sin\theta=\frac{x-\frac12}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}},\,\,\cos\theta=\frac{\frac{\sqrt3}2}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}$$
$$\begin{align}\int\frac{dx}{(x-1)\sqrt{x^2-x+1}} & =\ln\left(\frac{\frac{\sqrt3}2(x-\frac12)-\frac12\frac{\sqrt3}2}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}+\frac{\sqrt3}2\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac12(x-\frac12)}\right)+C_1 \\
& =\ln\left(\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}+\frac12x+\frac12}\right)+C\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $t=\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}\in (-1,2]$ to  have
$$ dt = -\frac{3(x-1)}{2(x^2-x+1 )^{3/2}}dx,\>\>\>\>\>t^2-4=-\frac{3(x-1)^2}{x^2-x+1}
$$
and
\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{(x-1)\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}dx
=\int \frac{2}{t^2-4}dt=-\tanh^{-1}\frac t2+ C
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Euler's first substitution, $\sqrt{x^2 - x + 1} = x + t$, which gives $dx = - \frac{2(t^2 + t + 1)}{(2 t + 1)^2} dt$, transforms the integral to
$$2 \int \frac{dt}{(t + 2) t} = \int \left(\frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{t + 2}\right) dt = \log \frac{t}{t + 2} + C .$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
& \int \frac{dx}{(x-1)\sqrt{x^2-x+1}} \\
&= -2 \int \frac{dy}{\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}-1\right) \sqrt{\frac{(1-y)^2}{(1+y)^2}-\frac{1-y}{1+y}+1}\,(1+y)^2} \tag1 \\
&= \int \frac{dy}{y \sqrt{1+3y^2}} \\
&= \int \frac{dz}{z\sqrt{1+z^2}} \tag2 \\
&= \int \frac{\frac w{\sqrt{w^2-1}}}{\sqrt{w^2-1}\,w} \, dw \tag3 \\
&= \int \frac{dw}{w^2-1} \\
&= -\tanh^{-1} w + C
\end{align*}$$

---

- $(1)$ : substitute $x=\dfrac{1-y}{1+y} \iff y=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$
- $(2)$ : substitute $y=\dfrac z{\sqrt3} \iff z=\sqrt3\,y$
- $(3)$ : substitute $z=\sqrt{w^2-1} \iff w=\sqrt{1+z^2}$